# como crear un cron job apartir de un form, nextjs

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, nextjs, cron, schedule

quiero hacer un formulario para generar una programacion(SCHEDULE) con los datos obtenidos del mismo, lo que he logrado leer es que se necesita un server externo para lograr esto con nextjs, quisiera hacerlo en mi propia app un form schedule.
mi pregunta es la siguiente, como puedo lograr un simple form schedule y que este se ejecute luego desde mi propia app?

he pensado algo como los post de wordpress: cuando se crea un post este da la opcion de elegir cuando hacerlo visible, es esto posible desde la propia app sin necesidad de un servidor de tercero?

les agradeceria cualquier orientacion que me puedan dar, gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

Desde Next.js no vas a poder porque Next.js es una plataforma **serverless**, de hecho no existe un server, todos los endpoints son "serverless functions".

Algunas opciones son:

- Si usas Vercel: [Vercel Cron Jobs](https://vercel.com/docs/cron-jobs/)
- [Qstash](https://upstash.com/docs/qstash/overall/getstarted) (yo uso esta plataforma para mis cronjobs).
- [Slater](https://tryslater.com/)

Hay más plataformas que te ofrecen un servicio similar a estas que te compartí.

BONUS: Te dejo el [crontab gurú](https://crontab.guru/) para que puedas verificar que tus cronjobs se van a ejecutar en el periodo de tiempo que esperas.

Comment: entiendo, muchas gracias por tu aclaracion